# Using OpenCV Mat for reading text using tesseract (Java)

Tags: java, opencv, tesseract, leptonica

I need to read text using tesseract, for my processed image which is done using OpenCV. I have already tried the methods mentioned in the following link, but to no avail:

**Method 1**

Converting using MatOfBytes [SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48868503/leptonica-opencv-java-convert-mat-to-pix-and-vise-versa)

```
public static PIX convertMatToPix(Mat mat) {

        LOGGER.info("Size of image: " + mat.size());
        MatOfByte bytes = new MatOfByte();
        Imgcodecs.imencode(".jpg", mat, bytes);
        ByteBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes.toArray());
        LOGGER.info("Size for pixReadMem: " + new NativeSize(buff.capacity()).intValue());
        return pixReadMem(buff, new NativeSize(buff.capacity()).intValue());
    }
```

This method creates a white image out of my input image.

**Method 2**

Converting using Byte Array

```
byte[] imageBuffer = new byte[(int) (input.rows()*input.cols()*input.channels())];
        input.get(0, 0, imageBuffer);
PIX image = pixReadMem(imageBuffer, (int) (input.rows()*input.cols()*input.channels()));
```

This method fails to create an image, as I am outputting image using:

```
int writingFromPix = pixWriteAutoFormat("/home/abhishekkeshri/Pictures/ocr/pixOutput.jpg", image);
LOGGER.info("Writing from PIX returns: " + writingFromPix);
```

And it is returning 1, which signifies an error in writing image.

**Method 3**

Copying pixel-by-pixel value ([SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39293922/convert-between-opencv-mat-and-leptonica-pix?rq=1))

```
PIX mat8ToPix(Mat mat8)
    {
        PIX pixd = pixCreate(mat8.width(), mat8.height(), mat8.depth());
        for(int y=0; y<mat8.rows(); y++) {
            for(int x=0; x<mat8.cols(); x++) {
                double[] pixelDouble = mat8.get(y,x);
                int[] pixelInt = new int[pixelDouble.length];
                for(int i=0;i<pixelDouble.length;i++) {
                    pixelInt[i] = (int) pixelDouble[i];
                }
                pixSetPixel(pixd, y, x, pixelInt[0]);
            }
        }
        return pixd;
    }
```

The problem in this method is that `get` method returns an array of pixel, which depends on the channel. So just using the 0th value should be wrong. The logic seems correct but what am I doing wrong in this method?

**Method 4**

Directly using `Mat` to `setImage` in Tesseract

```
api.SetImage(imageBuffer, input.width(), input.height(), input.channels(), (int)input.step1());
```

This method also fails to get any output from Tesseract, as the output printed is blank.

**Method 5**

By simply reading the preprocessed image, and reading it using tesseract the output given is correct:

```
PIX image = pixRead("/home/abhishekkeshri/Pictures/ocr/clean.jpg");
api.SetImage(image);
```

This gives the correct result. But I can't use this as disk operations will be quite costly (writing output of opencv and saving it in a file, the opening that file using PIX)

Any help will be appreciated, as I am stuck in this problem since 2 days.

My maven dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
        <artifactId>tesseract-platform</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0-rc2-1.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openpnp</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.2-1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.lept4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>lept4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used below code for convert Mat to BufferImage.

Tesseract Code:

```
Tesseract tesseract1 = new Tesseract();
tesseract1.setDatapath(datapath);
tesseract1.doOCR(Mat2BufferedImage(mat);
```

Mat to BufferdImage Convert code:

```
static BufferedImage Mat2BufferedImage(Mat matrix) throws Exception {
    MatOfByte mob = new MatOfByte();
    Imgcodecs.imencode(".jpg", matrix, mob);
    byte ba[] = mob.toArray();

    BufferedImage bi = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(ba));
    return bi;
}
```

Using this code getting expected output.