# Want to convert org.bytedeco.javacpp.lept.PIX to byte[] and Buffered Image

Tags: java, arrays, image-processing, bufferedimage, leptonica

I want to write a utility which converts `org.bytedeco.javacpp.lept.PIX` to `byte[]` and `BufferedImage`. I have tried the following:

1) using Java2DFrameUtils but it inverts my image colors ( 1-> 0 and 0-> 1) with the code:

```
LeptonicaFrameConverter c = new LeptonicaFrameConverter();
 Frame f = c.convert(src);
 BufferedImage img = Java2DFrameUtils.toBufferedImage(f);
```

2) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48868503/leptonica-opencv-java-convert-mat-to-pix-and-vise-versa) approach does not use the `org.bytedeco.javacpp` package, so it does not help me.

3) When I try to use `PointerPointer` and `SizeTPointer` of this package, I get error saying

```
"Error in pixWriteMem: &data not defined".
```

Here is my code:

```
    PointerPointer pp = new PointerPointer();
    SizeTPointer psize = new SizeTPointer();
    lept.pixWriteMem(pp, psize, src, lept.IFF_TIFF);
    byte[] by = pp.asByteBuffer().array();
    BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(by));
```

Any help would be appreciated. TIA.

Comment: Seems that the easiest solution would be to just invert the image from 1 then..?

Comment: I dont check the color coding at runtime. The behavior is not consistent for all images.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that I'm a bit late here. but if somebody reaches this post in the future, here is how I dealt with this issue.

The issue is that neither `buffer` nor `psize` are initialised.
So I use `0` as the size of the buffer, call `pixWriteMem` that returns the buffer size in the `psize` pointer. Then call `pixWriteMem` again with a buffer of the expected size.

*Caution*: If you work with very large images check the potential issues with the `toInt()` calls!

If something goes wrong and `gotSize` is always different of `size`, this can lead to an endless loop with a StackOverFlow exception.

The sample code is in Kotlin.

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
fun convertPixToImage(pix: PIX?, size: Int = 0): ByteArray {
    val buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(size)
    val psize = SizeTPointer(size.toLong())
    val format = IFF_PNG
    if (0 != lept.pixWriteMem(buffer, psize, pix, format)) {
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Cannot convert image")
    }
    val gotSize = psize.get().toInt()
    if (gotSize != size) {
        return convertPixToImage(pix, gotSize)
    }
    return buffer.array()
}
```